# Type un-erasure from a boost::program_options value

Tags: c++, templates, boost-program-options, boost-any

I'm trying to retrofit my program with `boost::program_options`. Among other things, I've written a function which I just can't get to compile. Here's a sort-of-minimal .cpp file which fails compilation:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

template <typename C, typename E>
inline bool contains(const C& container, const E& element) {
    return container.find(element) != container.end();
}

template <typename K, typename V>
V& updateFromConfig(V& updatee, const K& key, const po::variables_map& vm) {
    if (contains(vm, key)) {
        // option 1
        updatee = vm[key];
        // option 2
        //updatee = vm[key].variable_value();
        // option 3
        // updatee = vm[key].as<V>();
        // option 4
        // updatee = vm[key].as();
    }
    return updatee;
}

template size_t& updateFromConfig<char*,size_t>(size_t& updatee, char* const& key, const po::variables_map& vm);
```

With any of the four options I get a different compiler error:

- With option 1:

  ```
  cannot convert ‘const boost::program_options::variable_value’ to ‘long unsigned int’ in assignment
     updatee = vm[key];
  ```
- With option 2:

  ```
  invalid use of ‘boost::program_options::variable_value::variable_value’
  ```
- With option 3:

  ```
  18:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
  18:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
  ```
- With option 4:

  ```
  no matching function for call to ‘boost::program_options::variable_value::as() const
  ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Option 3 is the correct one.

Comment: @Barry: Here you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ syntax for the win. [Do](https://ideone.com/ifTVoe):

```
updatee = vm[key].template as<V>();
```

Comment: Saying why this template disambiguator is required might help the OP.  Or I could just Mjölnir the OP to a description...

Comment: Really? That is so bizarre... how can I put "template" in the middle of a statement? Can you perhaps link to somewhere explaining how this is  possible? I know about "typename" before types, but this is new to me.

Comment: @einpoklum See the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/1774667) pointer on your question now.  It explains in ... lots of detail.

Comment: @Yakk Hm? But `as` isn't a dependent name... `vm` isn't a template argument and `operator[]` isn't a function template either. Why would the `template` keyword matter?

Comment: @Barry [temp.dep.expr]/1 "Except as described below, an expression is type-dependent if any subexpression is type-dependent."  So, `vm[k]` is a dependent expression, unless excluded.  None of the exclusions apply (the fact that there is only one possible overload of `operator[]` that can be called is not listed as an exclusion).  Once dependent, `vm[k].as` is presumed to be not-a-template unless disambiguated.  The exceptions to viral type-dependency are mostly stuff like `static_cast` and `sizeof` and `new` etc.